# Efficently generate one random prime number in a range

Tags: java, performance, primes

I need to get only one random prime number in the range [2, n^2] where n can be very big (10^9 to 10^32). I know those homework questions "how to print prime numbers in a given range", "Eratosthene's sieve" etc.

I want, if possible, to avoid computing all prime numbers and select one at random.

I am also not sure if picking a random number from the range and check for primality is a elegant/efficent way of solving this issue.

This has nothing to do with security purposes. It's just part of an algorithm implementation (a try to implement) which checks if two very big files (>1TB) are identical or not.

Any ideas how to get one definitely prime random number with focus on performance?

**EDIT**
A very naive and simplified implementation of what i am trying to do:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class NewClass1 {    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //imagine this is my content of first file which is not at the same place as file two
        String file1 = "RDNZL";        
        //convert the content to bits
        file1 = toBits(file1); // 0101001001000100010011100101101001001100  

        //convert bits to number
        BigInteger  x = new BigInteger (file1, 2); //353333303884

        long p = 1187;  // select a random number between 2 and 1600 (String length * 8 bits = 40)
        // send p and x % p to validiate,
        long xMp = x.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(p)).longValue(); 
        System.out.println(check(p, xMp));
    }
    public static String toBits(String file){
        //convert each char to 8 bits and concat to string
        //just for simplification, i'am going to find a better way to solve this
        return file.chars().boxed()
                .map(Integer::toBinaryString).map(e->String.format("%8s", e).replace(' ', '0'))
                .collect(Collectors.joining("")); 
    }
    public static boolean check(long p, long xMp){
        //the other file which is somewhere else, in the cloud etc. 
        String file2 = "RDNZL";        
        file2 = toBits(file2); 

        BigInteger  y = new BigInteger (file2, 2); 
        long yMp = y.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(p)).longValue();
        return yMp == xMp;
    }
}
```

If yMp != xMp with 100% confidence files differ, if not an infinitesimal chance that the algorithm doesn't recognize it that they differ.

Comment: Are you expecting all primes within the range to be equally likely to be chosen?

Comment: Why do you need prime numbers to check if 2 files are identical?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem just a random number from the range and definitely prime. I do not care about the distirbution/  equally likely to be chosen

Comment: @ThomasWeller  I do not want to compare the files line by line. I have found a theoretical algorithm and i am trying to implement it.

Comment: @ThomasWeller that may be true. Didn't saw it from that point of view. Thank you. I will post a minimal complete example soon, could be grate if you would take a look at it.

Comment: So you could just pick a random BigInteger within the range, then iterate downwards testing everything until you find a prime.  As Thomas' answer points out, you'd end up testing about 150 numbers on average.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how does computing a large, random prime number help you determine whether two very big files (>1TB) are identical or not?  Is your algorithm faster than computing and comparing a hash on each file?

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak: AFAIK bvckup2 uses an algorithm which hashes parts of the file, so yes, there can be faster algorithms than simple hashing. I still can't think how a prime number would help.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Is that algorithm just breaking up the file to try to get lucky (or benefit from heuristics, like 99% of changes affect the 1st 5% or the last 5% of a file)?  Or is there really some CompSci magic that lets them compare two files without actually looking at them?  In otherwords, is that backup algorithm better than simple hashing in the worst case?  I'm really curious.  Thanks.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak: the developers are quite open about the implementation and talk about it in the [bvckup2 forum](https://bvckup2.com/support/forum/). It seems that their hashing is simply done in blocks, but they can start copying parts of the file earlier and likely better benefit from caching. You find more about it with the term ["delta copying"](https://bvckup2.com/support/forum/topic/739). Also, they do a pretty good job with async IO and completion ports. I love their software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability to find a prime number at x is 1/ln(x). In your case, that's n² with n=10^32. So the likelyness is ln(10^64) or roughly 1/150. This means that you have to test an average of about 150 numbers until you find a prime.

I don't have Java available, but I can give you a result from Python, based on the [PSW primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baillie%E2%80%93PSW_primality_test). Credits go to [@primo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4098/primo) from [Codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), especially [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10702/16901).

```
start = time()
n = next_prime((10**32)**2)
end = time()
print (n, " calcualted in ", end-start)

10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000057 calcualted in  0.00302 sec
```

So yes, it is possible in an efficient way at the same time.

The result is confirmed by [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=nextprime((10%5E32)%5E2).

Comment: You haven't actually shown the calculation here.  You've just shown how to call a Python function and time how long it takes to run.  There is nothing usable for OP here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your example and the provided links. I'll definetly read and try to understand the maths.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem: well, sometimes, you just need to know the terms like "PSW primality test" and then you find some paper and implement it. Should be "helpful" and thus worth +1. But yeah, I found the original code and linked to it.

Comment: Maybe the prime density is 1/150, so the average lookup would be 1/75 only. I can't recall correctly.

Answer (score 3):

## Use [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,java.util.Random)), and its [`nextProbablePrime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#nextProbablePrime()) method.

```
public static BigInteger randomPrime(int numBits) {
  BigInteger max = BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(numBits);
  BigInteger prime;
  do {
    BigInteger integer = new BigInteger(numBits, ThreadLocalRandom.current()); // Pick a random number between 0 and 2 ^ numbits - 1
    prime = integer.nextProbablePrime(); // Pick the next prime. Caution, it can exceed n^numbits, hence the loop
  } while(prime.compareTo(max) > 0);
  return prime;
}
```

An alternative would be to use the `BigInteger​(int bitLength, int certainty, Random rnd)` constructor, but it will find numbers with exactly `bitLength` bits, which is inconvenient because it doesn't go below n ^ (bitLength - 1).

Comment: I think you're on the right track, but `BigInteger.nextProbalePrime()` does **not** return the next prime number, only the next *probable* prime. You would need to actually test the number to confirm it's a prime, then try again if it's not prime.

Comment: @Bohemian Fixed with an extra condition in the loop. The certainty of 100 is enough to make sure the probable prime is a prime for numbers lower than 10^32.

Comment: Just note that certainty is not a percentage. Specifying `certainty` means is the probability of it *not* being a prime is less than 1/2^certainty.

Comment: I agree to @Bohemian. That `isProbablePrime()` is redundant to `nextProbablePrime()`, because [`nextprobablePrime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#nextProbablePrime()) already uses the certainty of 100 ("does not exceed 2^-100.").

Comment: With the caveat that this has a *very* skewed distribution, not uniform.  For uniform selection one should repeatedly select a random integer in the range and do a primality test (there are some optimizations).  The nextprime method is easier to write efficiently and sometimes one doesn't care about the non-uniformity.